# Auto-generate emails for only Monday

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following snippet of code within my onload function. Checking to see if the date is Monday and if so then check within the log_EmailProductionSchedule to see if todays date is logged. If not the app will automatically send the email and add a log to this table with todays date, preventing the application from sending another email. However, each time I open the application the email is being generated and a new log is being inserted. where have I gone wrong with this code?

```
If Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Then
    If DCount("*", "log_EmailProductionSchedule", "[sentDate] = #" & Format(Now, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#") = 0 Then
        'send email
        Call SendProductionEmail
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT into log_EmailProductionSchedule (sentDate) select date()")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: it has logged correctly as 24/02/2020, perhaps this is because of the format check  being mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Eh... What's the structure of the table? Also, generally, avoid using string concatenation: `If DCount("*", "log_EmailProductionSchedule", "[sentDate] = Date()") = 0`. No need to cast the date to a string, then to an SQL date literal, that's error-prone.

Comment: The table is just and ID = Autonumber & sentDate = Date/Time (Format Short Date)

Comment: Your syntax "If DCount("*", "log_EmailProductionSchedule", "[sentDate] = Date()") = 0" seems to have done the trick. I think the string format must have been doing something to prevent it from matching the date format within the table

Answer (score 1):

Set a break point on `DCount`. Your variables are probably not being set to what you think they are.

Instead if messing around with `Format` just use the date function

```
If Weekday(Now) = vbMonday Then
    If DCount("*", "log_EmailProductionSchedule", "[sentDate] = Date()") = 0 Then
        'send email
        Call SendProductionEmail
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT into log_EmailProductionSchedule (sentDate) select date()")
    End If
End If
```

[click here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) to learn about the peculiarities with VBA and SQL in MS Access. TL:DR; Jet, the database engine that runs your SQL uses whatever your machine regional settings are, but VBA is fixed to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: pointed noted, amended to reflect. Shouldn't have Ctrl-F 'Now'